# How do I complete a form using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I want to log in that website, but can't add my credentials.

The first part of my code is:

```
from selenium import webdriver

PATH = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.maximize_window()

driver.get('https://glovoapp.com/ro/buc/store/kaufland-buc/')

login = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="user-login"]')

login.click()
```

After that, tried using `find_element_by_xpath()` and a few other methods, but none of them worked, as it either says "Unable to locate element" or "element not interactable". How can I do it? In previous examples I have followed I could find it with `find_view_by_id()` but now I encounter some problems.

Comment: what problems are you facing exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To log in that website you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://glovoapp.com/ro/buc/store/kaufland-buc/")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#user-login"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#login-email div input"))).send_keys("AlexBebereche@stackoverflow.com")
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://glovoapp.com/ro/buc/store/kaufland-buc/")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@id='user-login']"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='login-email']//following::input[@data-test-id='text-field-input']"))).send_keys("AlexBebereche@stackoverflow.com")
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Browser Snapshot:

[image: glovoapp]

Comment: I managed to do what I wanted, you saved me a lot of time, thank you!